# Hibernate Nested SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

There are two tables

Table abc and xyz

Key for abc - customerID

Key for xyz - (customerID, customer_name)

I have a nested query of the following pattern

```
"select * from abc whrere customerID in ( select customerID from xyz where customer_name='rohit')"
```

How to query this in Hibernate using Criteria only ?

Comment: use createQuery for above scenario.

Comment: Can this be done using Criteria ??

Comment: I have not tried to write a query in CreateCriteria. I Used createQuery
createSQLQuery for sql queries.But you can try.And share the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for the above question.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(abc.class);
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria
         .forClass(xyz.class)  
         .setProjection(Property.forName("customerID"));
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("customerName","rohit"));
criteria.add(Property
                    .forName("customerID")
                    .in(detachedCriteria));
```

Answer (score 0):

**[16.13. Subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)**

Should be

```
from abc whrere customerID in ( select customerID from xyz where customer_name='rohit')
```